# Memory profiling a Tomcat application

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

I'm trying to profile an application I'm running on Tomcat, but there's something I don't understand. After capturing a snapshot with YourKit I get 936MB heap memory usage and 402MB non-heap. But when I run `pmap` I get a total of 8GB (see below for an abbreviated version, the full version is [here](https://justpaste.it/6vbnc)). What's the cause of the difference?

Also, I expected two of the entries in `pmap` to reflect the heap and non-heap memory sizes but I see nothing close. Why is that?

```
00007fc6d17f0000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6d19f0000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6d2a63000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6d3296000   2048K -----  /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
00007fc6d3df0000   2048K -----  /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
00007fc7102a5000   2048K -----  /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
00007fc71090c000   2048K -----  /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k
00007fc710b9f000   2048K -----  /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k
00007fc711031000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc7118d8000   2048K -----  /lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.3-20140911.so.1
00007fc72c001000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc72c648000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc72c848000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc72cfcf000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc72d1cf000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc72d3cf000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc72d7e0000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc72d9e0000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc72dbf6000   2048K -----  /lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
00007fc734325000   2048K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc734c9a000   2048K -----  /home/someuser/java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
00007fc7740de000   2048K -----  /home/someuser/java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
00007fc77609b000   2048K -----  /home/someuser/yoni/libyjpagent.so
00007fc7764f5000   2048K -----  /home/someuser/java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
00007fc7778dd000   2048K -----  /home/someuser/java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
00007fc777db9000   2048K -----  /lib64/libc-2.17.so
00007fc7783f4000   2048K -----  /lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
00007fc682767000   2112K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc682be0000   2112K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc72c438000   2112K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc7106db000   2244K r-x--  /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k
00007fc700000000   2272K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc730000000   2512K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc680213000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc681a79000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc688a9a000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc689144000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc689c56000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc68a6db000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc68ab73000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6b46fe000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6b5488000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6b5d0a000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6b640c000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6b75c1000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6b7a42000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6b89e3000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6b8de7000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6b916a000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6ba084000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6bab12000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6bbd82000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6c877a000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6c8dfb000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6c92fd000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6c9880000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6c9b01000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6c9d82000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6d0160000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6d065e000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6d0f72000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6d24e3000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6d27e5000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc711645000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc72cd51000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc7340a7000   2552K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc748000000   2920K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc760b40000   3244K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc744000000   3272K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc734906000   3576K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6e4000000   3660K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6ec000000   3684K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc70c000000   3780K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6dc000000   4212K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6f0000000   4716K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc775bca000   4932K r-x--  /home/someuser/yoni/libyjpagent.so
00007fc73ac00000   5120K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc73b100000   5120K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc73b600000   5120K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc73bb00000   5120K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc740000000   5504K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc73c000000   7800K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc67b7e2000   8312K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc74c000000  10464K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc71c000000  11168K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc776c01000  13168K r-x--  /home/someuser/java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
00007fc720000000  13744K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc75c000000  14104K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc758000000  14248K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6ff107000  15332K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc6e8000000  15520K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6d4000000  18500K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc774825000  20116K rw---    [ anon ]
00000007e0800000  21836K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6da745000  25324K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc754000000  25852K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc67e0e1000  31868K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc72e000000  32768K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc67c000000  33668K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc75593f000  39684K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc6d8000000  40212K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc738400000  40960K rw---    [ anon ]
0000000000a26000  42588K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6c14e4000  44144K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc6d5211000  47036K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc735400000  49152K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6e8f28000  50016K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc6fc000000  50204K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc758dea000  51288K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc75cdc6000  51432K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc720d6c000  51792K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc71cae8000  54368K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc74ca38000  55072K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc678000000  57224K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc73c79e000  57736K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc740560000  60032K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc6f049b000  60820K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc6dc41d000  61324K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc70c3b1000  61756K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc6ec399000  61852K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc6e4393000  61876K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc744332000  62264K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc7482da000  62616K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc730274000  63024K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc700238000  63264K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc6f81b5000  63788K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc7501ad000  63820K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc72814c000  64208K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc718061000  65148K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc704024000  65392K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc674000000  65516K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6b0000000  65516K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6f4000000  65532K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc684000000  65536K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6c4000000  65536K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6cc000000  65536K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6e0000000  65536K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc708000000  65536K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc724000000  65536K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc770000000  65536K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc68b481000  77308K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6bc000000  86928K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc711ad9000 103580K r----  /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
00007fc769a90000 103872K -----    [ anon ]
00007fc690000000 131072K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc698000000 131072K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6a0000000 131072K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc6a8000000 131072K rw---    [ anon ]
00007fc761000000 141888K rwx--    [ anon ]
00000007e1d53000 1026740K -----    [ anon ]
0000000740800000 2621440K rw---    [ anon ]
 total          8035196K
```

Comment: I wonder what that 936MB statistic is. Actual used heap space, or the total size of the heap? I am guessing the former and the virtual machine has actually reserved a very large heap. You should be able to see the complete virtual machine statistics in your profiler when you connect to the running Java process. It would also be interesting to see what -Xms and -Xmx settings are active.

Comment: `-Xms2048m -Xmx2560m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=128m -server -d64 -Xss512k`